# Loading a view inside a function not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

I got some weird error (CodeIgniter) :

Call to undefined function view().

However I am using login as default controller. index() is loading the page perfectly while loading the view in the function doesn't work.

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


 class Login extends CI_Controller{



public function index(){
    $this->load->view('login_view');
}

public function processLogin(){
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
        if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
            $this->load->model("user");
            $suc = $this->user->login($_POST['username'],$_POST['password']);

            if($suc !=0 && $suc !=-1){

            }
            else{
                if($suc == 0){
                    $data['error'] = "Invalid credentials";
                    $this->load>view('login_view',$data);
                }
                else{
                    $data['error'] = "Multiple user exist with same logon";
                    $this->load>view('login_view',$data);
                }


            }

        }
    }
}



}

?>
```

Comment: You have syntax error in your code. `$this->load>view('login_view',$data);` Is this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have miss a `-` near `>`

change this:

```
 if($suc == 0){
                    $data['error'] = "Invalid credentials";
                    $this->load>view('login_view',$data);
                }
                else{
                    $data['error'] = "Multiple user exist with same logon";
                    $this->load>view('login_view',$data);
                }
```

to this:

```
if($suc == 0){
                $data['error'] = "Invalid credentials";
                $this->load->view('login_view',$data);
            }
            else{
                $data['error'] = "Multiple user exist with same logon";
                $this->load->view('login_view',$data);
            }
```

I have change in two lines this: `$this->load>view` to this: `$this->load->view`

Comment: Incidentally, I think it's probably worthwhile mentioning the value of tools for checking syntax for catching stuff like this. Most text editors and IDE's either support that natively or can do so with plugins - I use Syntastic in Vim

Comment: Er, what? All I meant was that the OP would likely never have encountered this problem if they were using some kind of syntax checking tool